# Django - How to display search term on results page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I’ve made a successful form and it’s working accordingly displaying the search results when a user makes a form submission. However, I’m stuck with one new addition to this search functionality.

How do I get to display the search term with my current code?

I’m trying to display the current search term in `search_results.html` but can’t get the term to display work. The only thing that appears is a blank space. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in `views.py` but don't know what exactly.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**search_results.html**

`<h1>Results for "search term here {{ title_contains_query }}”</h1>`

**base.html (Where the search bar is located)**

```
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form method="get" action="{% url 'search_results' %}">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control gs-search-bar" placeholder="Search GameStation Games..." value="">
                            <span class="search-clear">x</span>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search-button">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                                </span> 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**views.py**

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def BootstrapFilterView(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.all()

    title_contains_query = request.GET.get('q')

    if is_valid_queryparam(title_contains_query):
        user_profile_games_filter = user_profile_games_filter.filter(game_title__icontains=title_contains_query)


    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter
       }

        
    return render(request, "search_results.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Had to add `'title_contains_query' : title_contains_query` to the `if\else` statement in `views.py`

Resolution below:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'user_profile': user_profile,  
        'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter,
        'user_prices': user_prices,
        'title_contains_query' : title_contains_query
  
    }

else:
    context = {
        'user_profile': user_profile,
        'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter,
        'user_prices': user_prices,
        'title_contains_query' : title_contains_query
   }
```